# Do the restrictions start at night or day?

Tags: fast-days, music, hair, three-weeks, shaving

Do the restrictions for the three weeks (music, haircuts, shaving, etc.) begin by sundown before the fast (17 Tammuz), or at the start of the fast (morning of 17 Tammuz)?